# How do I add a folder or all images in a folder to Compiz Wallpaper's background list?

Tags: compiz, desktop-background

I have over 100 images in my backgrounds folder. Is there an easy way to have Compiz Wallpaper use all images in a specified directory? Or is there a way to add all images easily from a folder to this list of background images? Adding each image at a time would be a time consuming task. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks in advance,
menturi

Comment: Are you willing to have 100 wallpapers as your background! or want a background which will rotate/change in those 100 image cycle

Comment: Sorry; I should have been more clear on the reason behind the original question. Compiz Wallpaper had a feature to have backgrounds cycle through after a period of time. It also has a feature where there can be different backgrounds for each workspace. These two features are what what I am primarily looking for.

Comment: This question is about a compiz feature. Not a feature like making image slideshow or something. The second edit revision was a radical change

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this inside of compiz/unity but try wallch. It works wonders with my several thousand wallpapers.

http://wall-changer.sourceforge.net/

it's also in the repos

```
sudo apt-get install wallch
```